# Elasticsearch extract/add id's from multiple queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple queries that need to filter data on elasticsearch. This queries are returning document ids from indexes that match the filter.

However i need to do another operation depending from user selection, to extract/add document unique id's from previous sum of queries with current query. The maximum number of query search is 5.

Is there an option in elastic so it will extract/add document id's from previous query? Right now i am doing this part in PHP with foreach iteration that takes a lot of time.

Edit 
Example :

Ok let say we have one query on same index that contains :

```
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"wildcard":{"182_empanalyzed":"example"}}]}}}
```

we will need to substract the document ids from the following query on same index :

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must_not":[{"nested":{"path":"184","query":{"exists":{"field":"184.*"}}}}]}}}
```

Keep in mind that this queries are example with only one condition in it, there might be more complexes queries with many fields to be searched on in each query. And from each following query there is an option to substract/add documents ids

Comment: Can you show some concrete example?

Comment: Ok, original question is edited

Comment: You can easily gather the document IDs from the first query and then add them to a `bool/must_not/terms` query in the second query, right?

Comment: I will try this but then what happen with performance if let say we have 1m records from first query ? Have you tried bool/must_not/terms with many records ? How do they preform?

Comment: You'd never get 1M records in a single response to the first query, at most 10K.

Comment: Than this want work because the idea is to add/substract document ids from previous query up to 5 queries for one function. We will not have all id's that needs to  substract/add or to be substracted/added.